# Python "return self.attrs[key]" error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to write a very simple python/beautiful soup script

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
my_url = 'https://www.travelok.com/listings/sid.1?last_region=&searchFormText=camping'
uclient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
filename = "oklahoma_state_parks.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "park_name, park_phone, \n"
f.write (headers)
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
containers = page_soup.findAll("article", {"class":"search-result"})
```

**This is test code to make sure it works here.**

```
parkinfo_name_test = containers[0].h2.text
parkinfo_phone_test = containers[0].address.div.text

parkinfo_name_test_2 = containers[2].h2.text
parkinfo_phone_test_2 = containers[2].address.div.text
```

**If I run the code to this point (everything above here) it works just fine.
I can print(parkinfo_name_test) and get the first result.  But when I try to loop it - it fails.  When I try to run it with the
code I get an error message:**

```
for container in containers:
    parkinfo_name = container[0].h2.text
    parkinfo_phone = container[0].address.div.text 

    print ("parkinfo_name: " + parkinfo_name)
    print ("parkinfo_phone " + parkinfo_phone)

    f.write (parkinfo_name + "," + parkinfo_phone + "\n")
    f.close ()
```

**This is the error message I get:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "oklahoma_state_parks.py", line 43, in   parkinfo_name = container[0].h2.text

File "C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.6.1-py3.7.egg\bs4\element.py", 
line 1071, in __getitem__return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0**

Comment: replace `container[0]` with `container`, once you iterate `containers` `container = containers[0]`

Comment: Yep - that [0] was the problem.   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
for container in containers:
    parkinfo_name = container[0].h2.text
```

Try doing it this way:

```
for container in containers:
    parkinfo_name = container.h2.text
    parkinfo_phone = container.address.div.text 

    print ("parkinfo_name: " + parkinfo_name)
    print ("parkinfo_phone " + parkinfo_phone)

    f.write (parkinfo_name + "," + parkinfo_phone + "\n")
    f.close ()
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!